# Remove underline and blue color from link

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html

I'm trying to disable two anchor tags and I can't get the underline removed.  I'd like to also remove the blue color.  Here's what I have an it's not removing the underline.  I've tried text-decoration set to `none` and `none !important`

```
        $(document).ready(function ()
        {
            // See if doc upload View and Remove panel is displayed --> do they currently have a document uploaded 
            var isInline = $("#ctl00_contentMain_pnlAuthorizationForReleaseViewUploadDocument").css('display');

            // if so disable upload and electronic sig links
            if (isInline == "inline")
            {
                //Disable Upload Link after document is uploaded
                $("#ctl00_contentMain_btnUpload").attr('onclick', '').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $("#ctl00_contentMain_btnUpload").attr('href', '');
                $("#ctl00_contentMain_btnUpload").attr('text-decoration', 'none !important');

                //Disable Electronic Sign Link after document is uploaded
                $("#ctl00_contentMain_lnkESign").attr('onclick', '').click(function (e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                });
                $("#ctl00_contentMain_lnkESign").attr('href', '');
                $("#ctl00_contentMain_lnkESign").attr('text-decoration', 'none !important');
            }

        });
```

Here is `aspx` code

```
<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkESign" 
                runat="server" 
                Text="sign"  
                TabIndex="1" 
                OnClick="lnkESign_Click">

<asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDownloadReleasefrm" runat="server" Text="Download"
                                        TabIndex="1"></asp:LinkButton>

Which renders this HTML

<a id="ctl00_contentMain_lnkESign" href="" tabindex="1" onclick="" text-decoration="none !important">sign</a>

<a href="" tabindex="2" id="ctl00_contentMain_btnUpload" onclick="" text-decoration="none !important">Upload </a>
```

---

edit

here's the code that i ended up using

```
    $("#ctl00_contentMain_btnUpload").attr('href', '').css('text-decoration', 'none').css('color', 'black').attr('onclick', '').click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Comment: Good practice note: You should consider storing the objects `$("#ctl00_contentMain_lnkESign") $("#ctl00_contentMain_btnUpload")` in single variables instead of always requesting them to the DOM.

Comment: fmsf  is there a particular reason to do that?

Comment: I wrote an article that covers is: http://franciscomsferreira.blogspot.com/2013/01/how-to-write-maintainable-javascript-or.html

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`text-decoration` is not an attribute.. It's a rule in css. You should try like below,

```
$("#ctl00_contentMain_lnkESign").css('text-decoration', 'none');
```

**Note:** No need for `!important` as it this is going to be an inline style.

Comment: will it make text-decoration: none for even hover and onclick event

Comment: No, It wouldn't make `text-decoration:none` for hover. Not sure what you mean by `onclick` event.

Comment: by onclick i mean, when i click any anchor tag to which i have given the id like above, when i click that anchor tag, then 'text-decoration' is not none.

Answer (score 2):

instead of `.attr(key, value)` use `.css(key, value)`

you won't be able change :hover, :visited etc colors, as these pseudo-styles only work in a stylesheet.  it might make sense to add a class to your css file like `.disabled` and then add that css class to the link with `.addClass()`

Answer (score 1):

You may also want to consider defining a class in your stylesheet for disabled anchors that controls both the `color` and `text-decoration` and use jquery to toggle that class instead of using inline styles.

**CSS**

```
/* Applied to all anchors for default enabled appearance */
.anchor
{
  ...
}

/* Applied to display a disabled anchor */
.anchor.disabled
{
  color: #ddd;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

**JavaScript**

```
$("#ctl00_contentMain_lnkESign").toggleClass('disabled');
```